# .NET MAUI 8: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException on initializing the main view with dependency injection

Tags: dependencies, maui, code-injection

There has never been any problem with the following code:

```
public partial class SelectionPage : ContentPage
{
    private SelectionViewModel vm;

    public SelectionPage(SelectionViewModel viewmodel)
    {
       InitializeComponent();
       this.vm = viewmodel;
       BindingContext = viewmodel;
       viewmodel.PropertyChanged += Viewmodel_PropertyChanged;
    }
```

But when I install it on a **new device**, or on a **new Simulator** I get the following error:
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'

I found a **strange workaround** which allows me to continue development for the moment:
If I comment out the line:
`// BindingContext = viewmodel;`
I can deploy the app on my device.
Once it has been successfully deployed I can reactivate `BindingContext = viewmodel;` and it works.

Of course I have to find the cause of this bug in order to make my app available to my testers.
I am grateful for all tips.

Comment: what does the InnerException property show?

Comment: InnerException:
-  InnerException {System.NullReferenceException} System.NullReferenceException

  Message "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." string

  Message "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation." string
  Source "System.Private.CoreLib" string

  Source "System.Private.CoreLib" string

I have no idea which object reference is null.

Comment: @Jason: Thank you. NullReferenceException, of course! First time initializing produced an unhandled exception.

Comment: Did you both add the dependency injection for the page and view model? Such as : `Services.AddTransient(typeof(SelectionViewModel)).AddTransient(typeof(SelectionPage));`

Comment: @Liyun Zhang - MSFT: Thank you. It was an initializing problem. I tried to close this question. But I cannot find any button to close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is good practice to have a look at the inner exception. Thank you @Jason for that tip.
A TargetInvocationException may pop up during initialization with dependency injection whenever there is a previous unhandled exception. In my case this unhandled exception was thrown only on first time installation, for example on a new device or a new emulator.